# Rails upgrade from 2.3.4 to 2.3.15 gives ActionView::TemplateError

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have an application running on Ruby[1.8.7] and Rails 2.3.4, now on upgrade to Rails 2.3.15 (along with its dependencies). It start throwing this error in 'Production' environment

```
ActionView::TemplateError (mass_update_mygroups_url failed to generate from {:action=>"show", :my_group_name=>"Production", :id=>"show", :controller=>"admin/mygroups"}, expected: {:action=>"mass_update", :controller=>"admin/mygroups"}, diff: {:action=>"mass_update", :my_group_name=>"Production", :id=>"show"}) on line #64 of app/views/admin/mygroups/show.html.erb:
61: </div>
62: 
63: <div class="table-wrap">
64: <% form_remote_tag  :url =>mass_update_mygroups_path(@data,params.except(:mass_update,:service_profile,:app_details)), :loading=>"document.getElementById('lightboxs').style.display='inline';",:complete=>"constructCollapsableFieldsets();document.getElementById('lightboxs').style.display='none';", :html=>{:id=>"m_update", :name=>"m_update"} do %>
65: <fieldset id="f2" name="f1" style="border: 1px solid #ccc;" collapsed="true">
66: <legend style="margin-left: 20px; padding: 2px 10px 4px 5px; line-height:0px;" align="left">Mass Update</legend>
67: <div class="form-wrap">

    (eval):21:in `mass_update_mygroups_path'
    app/views/admin/mygroups/show.html.erb:64
    passenger (2.2.11) lib/phusion_passenger/rack/request_handler.rb:92:in `process_request'
    passenger (2.2.11) lib/phusion_passenger/abstract_request_handler.rb:207:in `main_loop'
    passenger (2.2.11) lib/phusion_passenger/railz/application_spawner.rb:418:in `start_request_handler'
    passenger (2.2.11) lib/phusion_passenger/railz/application_spawner.rb:358:in `handle_spawn_application'
    passenger (2.2.11) lib/phusion_passenger/utils.rb:184:in `safe_fork'
    passenger (2.2.11) lib/phusion_passenger/railz/application_spawner.rb:354:in `handle_spawn_application'
    passenger (2.2.11) lib/phusion_passenger/abstract_server.rb:352:in `__send__'
    passenger (2.2.11) lib/phusion_passenger/abstract_server.rb:352:in `main_loop'
    passenger (2.2.11) lib/phusion_passenger/abstract_server.rb:196:in `start_synchronously'
    passenger (2.2.11) lib/phusion_passenger/abstract_server.rb:163:in `start'
    passenger (2.2.11) lib/phusion_passenger/railz/application_spawner.rb:213:in `start'
    passenger (2.2.11) lib/phusion_passenger/spawn_manager.rb:262:in `spawn_rails_application'
    passenger (2.2.11) lib/phusion_passenger/abstract_server_collection.rb:126:in `lookup_or_add'
    passenger (2.2.11) lib/phusion_passenger/spawn_manager.rb:256:in `spawn_rails_application'
    passenger (2.2.11) lib/phusion_passenger/abstract_server_collection.rb:80:in `synchronize'
    passenger (2.2.11) lib/phusion_passenger/abstract_server_collection.rb:79:in `synchronize'
    passenger (2.2.11) lib/phusion_passenger/spawn_manager.rb:255:in `spawn_rails_application'
    passenger (2.2.11) lib/phusion_passenger/spawn_manager.rb:154:in `spawn_application'
    passenger (2.2.11) lib/phusion_passenger/spawn_manager.rb:287:in `handle_spawn_application'
    passenger (2.2.11) lib/phusion_passenger/abstract_server.rb:352:in `__send__'
    passenger (2.2.11) lib/phusion_passenger/abstract_server.rb:352:in `main_loop'
    passenger (2.2.11) lib/phusion_passenger/abstract_server.rb:196:in `start_synchronously'
```

If I remove Rails 2.3.15 and switch back to 2.3.4 everything works fine again.
 More to this, things works perfectly fine on other box, there this upgrade does not give any problem and all the pages work properly even in production environment. 
 Difference in the these two box is one is centOS 5.4 (not working ) and centOS 6.3 (working) 
 Apart from this all the gems are of same version.

Comment: Are Ruby versions the same? What about gem versions? Bundler?

Comment: @Nazar Yes Ruby and all gems version are same

Comment: Assuming you can't upgrade to the latest version of Rails, why not upgrade to the latest version of Rails 2.3.x, which currently is 2.3.18? Otherwise, you'll be missing some [security fixes](https://github.com/rails/rails/commits/v2.3.18).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It might be late this is solved by resolving the passenger version also to 2.2.16